# What resources are available to help describe spell effects?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, narration

Are there any resources out there (tables, examples) to help describe spell effects to increase cinematic narrative?

Most spells in D&D 5e do not have much description as to specific somatic or verbal components. They also leave much open to interpretation as to how the outcome looks.

Rather than saying "I cast firebolt" I am looking for something that helps with visuals. I would prefer some examples like "I shout flame on!" while moving my fingers in the arcane patterns to summon fire. A bolt of blue fire jumps from my outstretched hand to singe the fur off the enemy.

Any material would be helpful it does not have to reference D&D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the books don't offer much in this regard, I suspect intentionally. But his is great, because that means you can make it up as you go. Here's two tips that are helpful in the two games I'm part of.

### You don't have to be the only one creating the narrative.

About the somatic and verbal components: as a DM I often ask my players to tell us *how* they want to cast it. Ask them about the color of their *Fire Bolt*; do they throw it, shoot it out of their palm? With one hand, or two? Or is it more like a fast fiery bullet from the finger? When you know their preference it gives you a frame in which you can experiment with the narrative. As far as I know the books don't often tell you literally how things are cast. With some spells they do however, like the infamous *Fireball*.

> A bright streak flashes from your pointing finger to a point you choose within range then blossoms with a low roar into an explosion of flame.

You could also play around with the material components in your narrative. Those are listed with the spells that require them.

### Use references as inspiration.

Don't be afraid to also lend inspiration from things you see in series, anime, films, etc. For example, my DM asked me how I want to *fey step*, so I said "like that guy in the first X-Men". For some tables that might break immersion, for us it helped us visualize and therefore increases it. Luckily as a DM you don't need to leave it at the mere reference, you can take that image and narrate it, and even spice it up with your phrasing (if needed). For example, I imagine the result of a *Fireball* to be similar to the result of a grenade. So I explain how the current situation would look after a grenade just hit it.

Comment: Found this blog which was a bit helpful. https://noblecrumpet-dorkvision.tumblr.com/post/157124404497/spellcasting-combat-narration-for-dd